# Integral equation I don't understand

Tags: integration

I don't understand this equation shared that I'm studying.

[image: pasted equation]

I understand that in line 2 he multiplies and divides by the same integral, 
but in the last line a reformulation happens and I don't get the properties used to obtain that.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $$\int_{I \in \Omega} v(I) (n \cdot I)^+ d I$$ is a constant, you can pull in into the integral if you wish, as the integral is linear: $a \int f(x) dx = \int a f(x) dx$.